# iOS: Replace IBOutlet with new view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, interface-builder

I have a UITableView that I created in IB and has an outlet tblHome in my view controller. I want to have it such that if the user is not running iOS7, then the table will be plain (it is set as grouped in IB).

I know that you can't change the style once its been created, so I'll have to change it. How can I replace the existing table with a new one?

The following did not work

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7)
{
    tblHome = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(tblHome.frame.origin.x, tblHome.frame.origin.y, tblHome.frame.size.width, tblHome.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You set the table style when you initialize the tableview.

USE UITableView programmatically  like below

```
 NSArray *vComp = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if ([[vComp objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7){
    tblHome = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
 }
else{
     tblHome = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information here yet. Where are you doing this check and overwrite?

If you don't use `initWithNibName:` to initialize your UIViewController it won't pull the settings from IB and you'll have to add the tableView manually via `addSubview:`

Step through your code with the debugger and make sure that on a sub iOS 7 device the line actually gets executed as expected.

Comment: I'm doing that in viewDidLoad. My project uses storyboard. I don't use initWithNibName to initialize my view controller. Should I put [tblHome removeFromSuperView] above the overwrite and then [self.view addSubView:tblHome] after the overwrite? And then set up the delegates and data sources? Is that all safe memory wise?

Comment: Hm I tried it. It replaced the view properly but then my prototype cells weren't configured properly. Maybe my best bet is to create two overlapped tableviews in IB, and then remove the one that isn't appropriate for the OS and set it to nil. Is that advisable?

Comment: I personally don't like using storyboards so I can't advise on that. Both options seem feasible - creating a second tableView in IB or programmatically setting up an overwrite tableView with all the identical settings. If you are doing it programmatically you'll have to make sure you copy all the settings from your story board. You might have missed something which caused the cells to misconfigure.

Comment: You could potentially create a custom UITableView subclass as well and set up different configurations methods for it. You could then manually add it in where you need to when laying out views, and configure it based on your OS version.